# How to convert a numeric values to text and replace one numeric value to specific word

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In an SQL query, I have a column, in which I want to convert numeric value type to text, that way I can replace only one numeric value which is -1 for the word Unknown, and leave the rest of the other values as it is.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can put `IsNull` and `NullIf` to good use here:

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 col union select 2 union select -1
)

select IsNull(NullIf(Convert(varchar(10), col), '-1'), 'Unknown') NewValue
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  col1 
       ,case when col1 = -1 then 'unknown' else cast(col1 as varchar(20)) end as new_col1
from    t
```

| col1 | new_col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| -1 | unknown |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| -1 | unknown |
| 1 | 1 |
| -1 | unknown |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9pul_nnu)